# AWS: The stream size for the streaming upload cannot be determined

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to do an upload of an image file from a temporary php file storage path to S3. The file size is around a 100 kb ranging to a maximum of 500 kb.

I get this error when the upload happens:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RequestCore_Exception' with message 'The stream size for the streaming upload cannot be determined.' in /var/www/project/releases/201303242100/application/libraries/AWS_SDK_1.6.0/lib/requestcore/requestcore.class.php:725
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/project/releases/201303242100/application/libraries/AWS_SDK_1.6.0/lib/requestcore/requestcore.class.php(843): RequestCore->prep_request()
#1 /var/www/project/releases/201303242100/application/libraries/AWS_SDK_1.6.0/services/s3.class.php(954): RequestCore->send_request()
#2 /var/www/project/releases/201303242100/application/libraries/AWS_SDK_1.6.0/services/s3.class.php(1465): AmazonS3->authenticate(
.....
```

I don't think I need a multipart upload here because the file is not too big. Also,the upload works from my local system to S3, but when I deploy the PHP instance on AWS, upload gives me the error. Any help will be appreciated.

THank you

Comment: If it will be of help, the uploaded file is an image file that is converted from a pdf file using Imagemagick. The Imagemagick convert command is in the code. Would the permissions to execute convert from code, cause this problem?

Comment: It would help if you can post code related to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the gd2 library which was being used for the image handling. After installing it everything worked like a charm! Thanks for the help!

Comment: softie - if it was the answer to your queistion - accept it please