# Can't determine filesize while uploading to s3

Tags: symfony, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload some files to amazon s3 bucket using `cybernox/amazon-webservices-bundle`. The problem is everytime I try to upload something, I suddenly get "The stream size for the streaming upload cannot be determined" error. What can be wrong here?

The code:

```
$s3 = $this->container->get('aws_s3');
$s3_bucket = 'name-eu';

$file_tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$file_name = $_FILES['file']['name']['photoUrl'];
$file_name = escapeshellcmd($file_name);
$file_ext = end(explode(".", $file_name));
$file_new_name = 'file_' . md5(rand(0,1000) . date("YmdHiS")) . '.' . $file_ext;

if(is_uploaded_file($file_tmp))
{
    $path = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/../../../../web/uploaded';

    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $path . '/' . $file_new_name);

    $s3->batch()->create_object('name-eu', 'uploaded/' . $file_new_name, [
         'fileUpload' => $path . '/' . $file_new_name,
         'body' => file_get_contents($path . '/' . $file_new_name),
         'acl' => $s3::ACL_PUBLIC,
             'headers'     => [
                 'Cache-Control' => 'max-age',
                 'Expires' => 'Sun, 17 Jan 2038 12:44:17 GMT'
             ]
         ]);

    $file_upload_response = $s3->batch()->send();
    $data->setPhotoUrl($file_new_name);
```

Comment: Hi there. There's another thread on this. See here :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15618722/aws-the-stream-size-for-the-streaming-upload-cannot-be-determined Looks like the same issue.